# How to solve "Specified cast is not valid" error when using linq query with multiple joins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to construct a Linq query in my repository that contains multiple joins from different tables in a database and then return this as an object for my controller to display. The error that I'm getting is: "Specified cast is not valid."

The problem part seems to be when I try to pass the object from my query and I'm not really sure how to solve this. (I'm still relatively new to web development and trying to learn the basics).

Below is the code in my repository:

```
public ListingModel GetListing(int listingId)
{
        var query = from listing in listingsTable
                    where listing.ListingID == listingId

                    join feature
                    in featuresTable on listing.ListingID equals feature.ListingID into features
                    from f in features.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    join avail
                    in availabilityTable on listing.ListingID equals avail.ListingID into availability
                    from a in availability.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    join image
                    in imageTable on listing.ListingID equals image.ListingID into images
                    from i in images.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    select new ListingModel
                    {
                        Listing = listing,
                        Features = features,
                        Availability = availability,
                        Images = images
                    };

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If it's needed, here's the ListingModel class:

```
public class ListingModel
{
    public Listing Listing { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Availability> Availability { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

When I try the query in LinqPad it works fine and returns the data exactly how I'd want it, so it seems to be erroring when I try to pass the object back. I've tried a few things with this and every time I seem to be getting the same error; I'm having real difficulty pinpointing what's causing it. Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting an anonymous object in your query and then using it to instantiate a `ListingModel` in memory.  The end of your method will look like this:

```
                select new
                {
                    Listing = listing,
                    Features = features,
                    Availability = availability,
                    Images = images
                };

    return query.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new ListingModel
                             {
                                 Listing = x.Listing,
                                 Features = x.Features,
                                 Availability = x.Availability,
                                 Images = x.Images
                             })
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

But can't you just take advantage of Foreign Key relationships and have LINQ to SQL join the associated tables for you?  Also, to avoid creating duplicate ListingModels you should remove the lines containing `DefaultIfEmpty()`.